# .click function ask me twice for confirmation

Tags: ajax, click

I have this issue, maybe you guys can help me fix it.

Botton Delete:

```
<button type="button" class="del-trade">Delete</button>
```

Ajax code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#modaledittrade").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $('.del-trade').click(function(){
      var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr( "data-id" );
        if( confirm( "Are you sure?") )
        {
        $.post( "actions.php?a=del-trade", { "id" : id },function(d){
          if( d.type!="ok" )
          {
            alert( d.msg );
            return;
          }
          $( "tr#" + id ).remove();
          resetForms( e.currentTarget );
          $( "#modaledittrade").modal('hide');
        },"json");
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

The code is give me loop twice... I mean ask me for function confirm() twice.
Video demo: http://sc.sny.pt/sJH6

Comment: Any help here? really I appreciate some help

Comment: You do know that `$("#modaledittrade").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $('.del-trade').click(function(){` adds a NEW click event handler on `.del-trade` every time you  fire the `"show.bs.modal" event right?

Answer (score 0):

On what I see, I think reason is because you create multiple instance of onclick event:

first time you delete (when modal is shown) create onclick event and the
second time that create a second event.

This should work :

```
$(function(){
    /*$("#modaledittrade").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {

    }); */


  $('.del-trade').click(function(){
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr( "data-id" );
      if( confirm( "Are you sure?") )
      {
      $.post( "actions.php?a=del-trade", { "id" : id },function(d){
        if( d.type!="ok" )
        {
          alert( d.msg );
          return;
        }
        $( "tr#" + id ).remove();
        resetForms( e.currentTarget );
        $( "#modaledittrade").modal('hide');
      },"json");
    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.
That way does not work because I need the .on("show.bs.modal" to get the **ID**

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the click event out, and this will still work as expected, using on:

```
$(document).on("click", '.del-trade', function(e){
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr( "data-id" ); // can still get ID same way

    if( confirm( "Are you sure?") )
    {
    $.post( "actions.php?a=del-trade", { "id" : id },function(d){
      if( d.type!="ok" )
      {
        alert( d.msg );
        return;
      }
      $( "tr#" + id ).remove();
      resetForms( e.currentTarget );
      $( "#modaledittrade").modal('hide');
    },"json");
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: Or, when the modal is hidden, turn off the delete click action:

```
$("#modaledittrade").on("hide.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $('.del-trade').off("click");
}); 

$("#modaledittrade").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $('.del-trade').on("click", function(e) { .. });
});
```

Comment: Getting invalid id
The function .on("show.bs.modal" is what is providing me the ID

Comment: See my edit then, during the hide method, you need to turn off the click event.